# How do you show an image retrieved from database in a DataWindow?

Tags: powerbuilder

In PowerBuilder .NET 12.5, I retrieve data from a database and display it in a DataWindow.
How can I also retrieve an image (in binary format) from the database and show it within the image control?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the new TableBlob column type?

http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/1765806